# Is there a way to grep with a constrained file type?

Tags: unix, grep, search

right now i am using something like this:

`find . -name "*.xml" | xargs grep -l "foobar"`

it works, but i was wondering if grep has this functionality built in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POSIX grep doesn't have such options, but `coreutils` grep does.

```
grep -r --include='*.xml' -l foobar .
```

should do it.

FreeBSD `grep` (and OS X) appear to have the same thing, Solaris & AIX lack them AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep -l "foobar" {} \;
```

Comment: yeah i used that originally but then switched to xargs because its faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com) where that command would be

```
ack --xml -l foobar
```

Note that `ack`'s filetypes mean that it doesn't just consider *.xml files.  Any file with the extension .xml, .dtd, .xsl, .xslt, or .ent will be selected for searching under the --xml flag.  See `ack --help-types` for a list of types and extensions.